# Manage many PhpStorm projects within only one Vagrant VM

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is it possible, or better, what's the way to manage many PhpStorm projects that uses only one Vagrant VM (based on VirtualBox) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can choose the Vagrant instance folder (Settings | Tools | Vagrant), and also you can configure mappings for the Vagrant PHP interpreter in PhpStorm, it's totally possible.

The only issue about that is how to place multiple projects into the same Vagrant VM.

1. If you have all projects located in the same folder, you can map this folder into the VM.
2. You can copy project files into the VM over SFTP with a PhpStorm deployment configuration.
3. Probably symlinking projects into the mapped folder could possibly work, it didn't work out for me though.